# C# WPF using Regex validation. How to check numbers between a range?

Tags: c#, regex, wpf, validation

I'm writing a program for Uni which requires some basic validation.

I have a textbox which allows the user to input their age. I have successfully written a Regex expression which checks if the value entered into the textbox contains numeric values only and is two characters long:

```
Regex agePattern = new Regex(@"^[0-9]{1,2}\z$"); // Age entered must be numeric characters only (0-9) and may only be two charaters long

        if (agePattern.IsMatch(ageBox.Text) == false)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Customer's age is not valid. Age must be in numeric format & can only be two characters long"); // If Regex pattern & entered string DO NOT match - user get's this message
            return;
        }
        else
        {
            // do something
        }
```

My question is, can I extend my Regex expression to constrain age values between 1 and 99?

I've not written any Regex before and I'm struggling.

Thanks!

Comment: `^[1-9][0-9]?$` ...

Answer (score 1):

How about parsing an integer instead?

```
bool IsValidAge(string ageString) {
   int age;
   return int.TryParse(ageString, out age) && age >= 1 && age <= 99;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this regex:

```
^[1-9]?[0-9]?\z
```

Or skip regex, parse the text as int and write a function which decide input is between 1 and 99.

Answer (score 0):

> Try this regex:
>
> ```
> ^[1-9]?[0-9]?\z
> ```

This matches an empty input (since both digits are optional) as well as `0`. Fewer `?` are better:

```
^[1-9][0-9]?$
```

Try it with [A Better .NET Regular Expression Tester](http://derekslager.com/blog/posts/2007/09/a-better-dotnet-regular-expression-tester.ashx) (most other online testers don't allow to specify an empty source).